# Group by chunks and get start and end times of each - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having trouble preparing the database output for my visualisation.

I have a table (in Oracle SQL) that monitors what (column 3) each computer (column 1) on my network does and when it started the action (column 2). See below:

```
# comps   ~ 20
# actions - 10
# rows    ~ 10_000

comp   |  time  |  action
-------+--------+----------
comp_1 | t_0    |    A
comp_1 | t_1    |    A
comp_2 | t_2    |    B
comp_1 | t_3    |    B
comp_1 | t_4    |    A
comp_2 | t_5    |    B
comp_2 | t_6    |    B
comp_1 | t_7    |    A
comp_1 | t_8    |    A
comp_2 | t_9    |    C
comp_2 | t_10   |    C
comp_1 | t_11   |    C
 ...     ...        ...
  .       .          .
```

End of the one action is beginning of the other action. Where B starts A ends. A may then be present again as a new "chunk" after B ends. Computer can do only one action at a time.

Time values are indeed Oracle `datetime` column (its only written as t_x for simplification).

I need help grouping the table by computer-action chunks, with start and end of each. `t_start` being the starting time of the query (from), and `t_end` is the ending (to).

This is my desired output:

```
comp   | action  | start   | end
-------+---------+---------+----------
comp_1 |   A     |  t_start|  t_3
comp_2 |   B     |  t_2    |  t_9
comp_1 |   B     |  t_3    |  t_4
comp_1 |   A     |  t_4    |  t_11
comp_2 |   C     |  t_9    |  t_end
comp_1 |   C     |  t_11   |  t_end
```

If you look carefully, you can see, that the records in the source tables may be overlapping, since every computer is reporting independently, but are allways chronological.

I was trying various group-by versions, but with no success. I'm suspecting, it may be more clever implementation of it or done by using "group-by having" or "over", but I'm not that skilled in SQL.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How do you know comp 1 finished its action A at t3 and not t9(or8)? Is it because it did a B at 3 and then did another A?

Comment: There's a technique where you can use LAG to look at the previous row's action, ordered by time (but you'll need to turn it numeric, if it really is an int prefixed with t_), and use a case when to see if it differed to the current row action, put a 1, or if it's same put a 0. Then you can use SUM OVER with a ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING qualifier to turn this column of alternating 1 and 0  into an incrementing counter that you can group by

Comment: It would b nice to know if your time column is really looking like that or if that is some obfuscated data and the time column is actually something that sorts nicely like a date or incrementing int

Comment: Thank you for responding. It is as you say, I will add that these important details (my bad) to the question. Look for its update.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pattern matching:

```
create table t (
  comp varchar2(10),
  time varchar2(10),
  action varchar2(1)
);

insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_00', 'A' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_01', 'A' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_2', 't_02', 'B' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_03', 'B' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_04', 'A' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_2', 't_05', 'B' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_2', 't_06', 'B' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_07', 'A' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_08', 'A' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_2', 't_09', 'C' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_2', 't_10', 'C' );
insert into t values ( 'comp_1', 't_11', 'C' );
commit;

select comp, st, 
       lead ( st ) over (
         partition by comp
         order by st
       ) en
from   t
  match_recognize (
    partition by comp
    order by time
    measures
      first ( time ) st
    pattern ( init same* )
    define
      same as action = prev ( action )
  );

COMP      ST      EN       
comp_1    t_00    t_03      
comp_1    t_03    t_04      
comp_1    t_04    t_11      
comp_1    t_11    <null>    
comp_2    t_02    t_09      
comp_2    t_09    <null>
```

- `same as action = prev ( action )` is true when the action for the current row is the same as the action for the previous row (defined by the partition and order by)
- The pattern is a regular expression, so `init same*` is one instance of `init`, followed by zero or more of `same`
- `init` is undefined so is "always true", matching the first row, then any row where the action is different to the previous row
- `lead` in the select returns the value for the next start

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll definitely look into this and report back my findings. Also I guess, adding the action name is as simple as adding it to the select, right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, didn't think I would get time to write this, hence the comment but:

Let's take the data and put a column with 0 or 1 depending on if the previous row's action was the same or different, per computer:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  CASE WHEN action = LAG(action) OVER(PARTITION BY computer ORDER BY time) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as differs
FROM
  t
```

Now let's turn the stream of 0 and 1 into a incrementing counter:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN action = LAG(action) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as differs
  FROM
    t
)

SELECT cte.*, SUM(differs) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as run_tot_dif
```

Now let's group by that counter per computer and take the min/max times. I note your times aren't an end of the current action but a start of the next action. For this we'll add a function in that picks the next time per computer for each row into the first cte so we can pick it later, and we'll also COALESCE it so that the nulls it causes at the end of the time period become :

```
WITH cte_diff AS(
  SELECT
    t.*,
    COALESCE(LEAD(time) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time), :endtime) next_start_time,
    CASE WHEN action = LAG(action) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as differs
  FROM
    t
  WHERE time BETWEEN :starttime and :endtime --parameterize it
), 
cte_runtot AS(
 SELECT 
   cte_diff.*, 
   SUM(differs) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as run_tot_dif
 FROM
   cte_diff
)

SELECT 
  comp, 
  action, 
  MIN(time) as start_time, 
  MAX(next_start_time) as end_time
FROM
  cte_runtot
GROUP BY
  comp, action, run_tot_dif
ORDER BY
  start_time
```

I'd point out that I think you made an error in your desired output - comp2's action B ran until comp2 started action C at t=9, not until comp1 started action A at t=7.. Unless I misunderstood your requirements

ps; you can collapse it somewhat by not using CTEs, but it might not mean that it's more readable:

```
SELECT 
  comp, 
  action, 
  MIN(time) as start_time, 
  MAX(next_start) as end_time
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    x.*, 
    SUM(diff) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as run_tot_diff 
  FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        t.*, 
        COALESCE(LEAD(time) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time), 9999) next_start,
        CASE WHEN action = LAG(action) OVER(PARTITION BY comp ORDER BY time) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END diff 
        FROM t
        WHERE time BETWEEN 0 and 11
    ) x
  )y
GROUP BY
  comp, action, run_tot_diff
ORDER BY
  start_time
```

It can't really be shrunk much more because Oracle doesn't allow window functions in GROUP BY, inside other window functions or inside aggregations (SQL Server takes less of an issue with it)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I'll try it right away. Also, you are right with the comp2 t_7/t_9.. it should really be at t_9. I'll correct it in the OP.